# Edit yaml file and save it with python

Tags: python, yaml

I have a yaml file that looks like this:

```
grids:
  phxgrid:
    class: spexxy.grid.FilesGrid
    filename: /home/geoffrey/Bureau/husser_interpolator/grid.csv

interpolators:
  phx:
    class: spexxy.interpolator.SplineInterpolator
    grid: phxgrid
    derivs: phxgrid

components:
  star:
    class: spexxy.component.GridComponent
    interpolator: phx
    init:
    - class:    
      values:
        logg: 4.0
        Alpha: 0.
        v: 0
        sig: 0


main:
  class: spexxy.main.ParamsFit
  components: [star]
  fixparams:
    star: [sig, Alpha, logg]
```

From a CSV file, I have to read a parameter in a column, which I already know how to do, and insert it in the yaml file to the line `logg: 4.0`, by example switching 4.0 to 3.2, and save a yaml file for each value.

Would you know how to do this? Thanks

EDIT:

So, for now, I have this:

```
import csv
import yaml
from csv import reader

with open('params.csv', 'r') as f:
        data = list(reader(f))
        logg_list = [i[6] for i in data[1::]]

with open('config.yaml', 'rw') as ymlfile:
        doc = yaml.load(ymlfile)

for logg in logg_list:
        doc['logg'] = logg[i]
        yaml.dump(doc,ymlfile)
```

But it does not change anything, and I'm not sure about the saving part as I'm supposed to obtain many yaml files with different values of logg, and I'd like to name the valid files in consequence

Comment: You can take a look at https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation library. But please show some code of what you have tried so far. SO is not intended to write full solutions for you

Comment: What have you tried so far? YAML is a very common format with lots of documentation. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: So far I have my code to take the value of logg in my csv file, I have then tried to make a loop to rewrite a yaml file for each value of logg with ```dict()``` and ```yaml.dump()``` but this is very tedious this way. I'd like to know if there is a way to open my already existing yalm file, edit it with the value of logg from the csv file, and then save it for every value of logg (~5000 so having ~5000 yalm files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to read the entire CSV file into memory. Read the YAML configuration in first, then write new YAML files as you iterate through the CSV file.

```
from csv import reader
import yaml


with open('config.yaml') as f:
    doc = yaml.load(f)

values = doc['components']['star']['init'][0]['values']
with open('params.csv') as f:
    for i, record in enumerate(reader(f)):
        values['logg'] = record[6]
        with open(f'config-{i}.yaml', 'w') as out:
            yaml.dump(doc, out)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried your way but it does not do anything, no error nothing, I don't know why actually

Comment: Looking at you YAML again, `doc['logg']` doesn't exist. It looks like you want something like `doc['components']['start']['init'][0]['values']['logg']` instead.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't think I had to write the all arborescence. But still, same result

Comment: What do you mean, "does nothing"? Does it read from the original YAML file? Is the loop iterating over your CSV file?  Does it create `config-1.yaml` et al. at all, or just copies of `config.yaml`?

Comment: Well actually literaly nothing, no error but the original yaml file is there, no iteration are made from what I see and no new ```congif-1.yaml``` file created.

Comment: Add some print statements to the code; you should see *some* output from them when you run the code, and that will help you figure out which parts aren't being reached.

Comment: My best guess right now would be that `params.csv` is empty.

Comment: Well, good guess ! I don't know how, must be from my previous attempts I accidentaly have erased the data, fortunately I saved it somewhere else. I now works fine, thank you very much !!